# NGINX (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying and reading

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, networking

hi all I have a problem with NGINX server 
this is the error that I`am receiving (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying and reading from upstream, client: 192.168.88.173, server: 0.0.0.0:443, upstream: "127.0.0.1:4445", bytes from/to client:452/3037, bytes from/to upstream:3037/697 
And its only happens when I try to open the site from Safari browser on MacOSX on Chrome and Firefox everything is okay tested on different osx computers all the same the browser saying
Safari can't open the page "https://xxxxxxx/" because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.

this is the config file NGINX.conf

```
  GNU nano 2.9.3                                                          nginx.conf                                                                     

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        keepalive_requests 256;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;


        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
```

`the domain config`

```
    location / {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 4444 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:4444 ssl http2;
    server_name class.feip.biz;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EDH+a$

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/class.feip.biz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/class.feip.biz/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
    proxy_buffers 8 16k; proxy_buffer_size 32k;
```